# Is there a Flutter widget/image transform library to produce a magnifying glass effect?

Tags: flutter, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to find a function or library that would let me apply an image transform effect on a widget or widgets that would achieve an effect similar to the attached image. Any ideas?

[image: Cat behind a glass pane]

Comment: `cv::remap` and a map that might use sin/cos or other wavy functions for coordinate calculations -- note that you asked for library recommendations. that's off-topic for stack overflow. see here: [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately at the time of this writing there are no packages that readily allow you to do this.